# Activating Ng-ApiMock Mocks on Angular 9 e2e Protractor Tests

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-e2e

I'm trying to implement ng-apimock on my Angular 9 app by

```
npm install @ng-apimock/core --save-dev
npm install @ng-apimock/protractor-plugin --save-dev
```

Then on protractor.conf.js I have added the plugin :

```
exports.config = {
    plugins: [{
      package: '@ng-apimock/protractor-plugin',
    }],
```

On my e2e test

```
import {Client} from '@ng-apimock/base-client';
declare const ngApimock: Client;
```

And inside the it () block

```
 ngApimock.selectScenario('login-mock, 'successful');
 element(by.id('loginBtn')).click();
```

BUT I don't know how to link the library to the login mock/scenario json